# How can I add the method to Math in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a method in Math object of javascript which calculates the logarithm of any base. So basically what I did was this:

```
Math.log_b=function(b,x){return Math.log(x)/Math.log(b);}
```

What is the downside of extending built-in function like this?

To make my situation more clear, I am taking the user input and replacing it with appropriate Math object function names and passing it to eval for the calculation. If this is not clear, my dilemma is, in my case, I have to use eval (even if it is evil) and extending the Math object function best suits my case.

Is there possibility of some weird bugs or other when I extend the built-in function like this or is it the perfectly normal things to do?

Comment: there is no Math() constructor so you cannot prototype it the math functions are only functions, not methods of an object.

Comment: Yes, it cannot be prototyped.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades yes it can be prototyped. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not modify what you don't own.

- What happens if another plugin or 3rd party code you use adds their own version of `log_b` to `Math`, which provides a completely different signature?
- What happen if a future version of JavaScript defines it's own version of `log_b` on `Math`?

Someone is going to cry, because for *someone* it wont do what they expect it to.

---

I'm not sure why extending `Math` *best suits your case*.

```
function my_log_b(b,x){return Math.log(x)/Math.log(b);}
```

... still seems to suit your case. Even better, define your own namespace, and put it in there;

```
var ME = {};

ME.log_b = function (b,x){return Math.log(x)/Math.log(b);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prototype it:

```
if (Math.__proto__) {
    Math.__proto__.log_b=function(b,x){ return this.log(x) / this.log(b); }
}
else {
    alert('Cannot prototype `Math`');
}
```

But it is probably not the best idea in that you *could* be overwriting browser code.

Better to add this method to an Object you made yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question? He has already added his own method to `Math` (which works http://jsfiddle.net/QnUsf/), he's asking if it's OK, no?

Comment: You're right; yours won't work in IE, which doesn't support the non-standard `__proto__`, where as his will :P.

Comment: @Matt baaah :-P That _might_ be true in bad browsers :-P

Comment: Meh, I'll remove my downvote, but you really don't need to prototype in the first place; `Math` is a living breathing object, which you can (universally) add methods to directly.